# HTTP request to the Authorization server using TLS Android

Tags: android, http, ssl, integration

I am new the android programming,I want to integrate the mixit social network in my app like facebook.To integrate the mixit I have to get the authorization request using Http connection using TLS.but I dont know how to write code for HTTP TLS connection.So please give me any guidance to proceed further.
Thanks in advance